# Sorting words in query in alphabetical order and remove duplicate words from individual rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort the words of a given query from each row of Pandas DataFrame and then remove duplicates from them. How can I perform this task on each row separately like : 
Given DataFrame :

```
Sr.No | Query
-------------
1.    war gears of war
2.    call of duty
3.    legend of troy legend
4.    resident evil
```

Resultant DataFrame should be :

```
Sr.No | Query
-------------
1.    gears of war
2.    call duty of 
3.    legend of troy
4.    evil resident
```

I am using split function to firstly split the words of each row of the data frame but it is not working.

```
for i in range(0,42365):
    temp2.iloc[[i]]=list(str(temp2.iloc[[i]]).split())
    print(temp2.iloc[[i]])
```

I get the following error:

> cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value.

Comment: You can just do `df['Query'].str.split()` to split the words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['war gears of war'],
        ['call of duty'],
        ['legend of troy legend'],
        ['resident evil'],  
    ], pd.Index(['1.', '2.', '3.', '4.'], name='Sr.No'), ['Query'])

df
```

[image]

#### Solution

```
df.Query.str.split().apply(lambda x: sorted(set(x))).str.join(' ').to_frame()
```

[image]

Comment: this is a nice one liner

Comment: Yes, your solution is much better, +1

Answer (score 1):

You can first create `Series` with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = df.col.str.split(expand=True).stack()
print (s)
0  0         war
   1       gears
   2          of
   3         war
1  0        call
   1          of
   2        duty
2  0      legend
   1          of
   2        troy
   3      legend
3  0    resident
   1        evil
dtype: object
```

Then `groupby` by first level and apply [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html). Last `join` all words:

```
print (s.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.sort_values().drop_duplicates())))
0      gears of war
1      call duty of
2    legend of troy
3     evil resident
dtype: object
```